# Angular, application can access the component even though route is not correct

Tags: angular, angular-router, angular-module

My application is constituted of several modules like this:

```
- account
- dashboard
- core
- authentication
```

The routes (quickly described):

```
// app.module
[{
  path: 'auth',
  canLoad: [authGuard], // check if token is missing
  loadChildren: 'authentication.module'
}, {
  path: 'app',
  canLoad: [appGuard], // check if token is not missing
  loadChildren: 'core.module'
}];
----------------
// core.module
[{
  path: 'account',
  loadChildren: 'account.module'
}]
----------------
// account.module
[{
  path: ':accountId',
  loadChildren: 'dashboard.module'
}]
```

The issue here, I am able to access the dashboard:

```
/authentication/dashboard
```

The correct URL should be:

```
/app/account/:accountId/dashboard
```

I miss something in the angular routing flow. Why am I able to access the dashboard even though the routing describes it differently?

Thanks for you help.

EDIT there was a mistake in the route object fo the auth route.

Comment: Because `dashboard` is, as far as the Angular router is concerned, a valid `:accountId`.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are putting your route path like this `path:':accountId'` at root level, change your path like below:

```
// core.module
[{
  path: 'account',
  loadChildren: 'account.module'
}]
----------------
// account.module
[{
  path: 'account/:accountId',
  loadChildren: 'dashboard.module'
}]
```

Comment: The url of this is now: /app/account/account/:accountId/dashboard, this is why i put it at root level. How to avoid account/account/?

Comment: @YoannPicquenot In your child routes default path should be path: '', so it will not duplicate with parent route like account/account. It's better if you also put your child routing here to check the issue.